# Como consigo alterar variável dentro do foreach?

Tags: php

Por favor, como altero a variável $logado  dentro if no foreach ?

```
<?php

session_start();

$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
$senha = $_REQUEST["senha"];
$logado = FALSE;

$usuario = array(
    "login" => "admin", "senha" => "admin",
    "login" => "admin1", "senha" => "admin1",
    "login" => "admin2", "senha" => "admin2",

);

foreach ($usuario as $user => $value) {
    if ($value === $login and $value === $senha) {
        $logado = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}

if ($logado) {
    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
    header("location: logado.php");
} else {
    echo '<h1>erro!</h1>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Redija melhor a sua pergunta, ela não esta clara.

Comment: Seu array `$usuario` tá cagado, você cria duas chaves, na primeira linha, e depois as sobrescreve, nas duas linhas seguintes.

Answer (score 0):

O que você está fazendo é uma array simples e tentando pegar dois valores distintos onde `$value` pode ser "login" ou "senha", e como os valores associativos são todos iguais, o `foreach` irá retornar apenas o último.

```
$usuario = array(
    "login" => "admin", "senha" => "admin",
    "login" => "admin1", "senha" => "admin1",
    "login" => "admin2", "senha" => "admin2",
);     ↑                    ↑
  mesmos nomes        mesmos nomes
```

O que você precisa fazer é criar uma array onde cada índice possua uma entrada `"login" => "valor", "senha" => "valor"` separada:

```
$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin", "senha" => "sadmin");
$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin1", "senha" => "sadmin1");
$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin2", "senha" => "sadmin2");
```

E no `foreach` você verifica "login" e "senha" usando colchetes:

```
foreach ($usuario as $user => $value) {
   if ($value['login'] === $login and $value['senha'] === $senha) {
      $logado = TRUE;
      break;
   }
}
```

Então o código ficará assim:

```
<?php
session_start();

$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
$senha = $_REQUEST["senha"];
$logado = FALSE;

$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin", "senha" => "sadmin");
$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin1", "senha" => "sadmin1");
$usuario[] = array("login" => "ladmin2", "senha" => "sadmin2");

foreach ($usuario as $user => $value) {
   if ($value['login'] === $login and $value['senha'] === $senha) {
      $logado = TRUE;
      break;
   }
}

if ($logado) {
    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
    header("location: logado.php");
} else {
    echo '<h1>erro!</h1>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Vlw dvd!

```
<?php

session_start();

$login = $_REQUEST["login"];
$senha = $_REQUEST["senha"];
$log1 = FALSE;
$log2 = FALSE;
$c =0;

$usuario = array(
    array("login" =>"ladmin", "senha" => "madmin"),
    array("login" => "ladmin1", "senha" => "madmin1"),
    array("login" => "ladmin2", "senha" => "madmin2"),
);

foreach ($usuario as $user => $v) {
    foreach ($usuario[$user] as $user2 => $value){       
        if ($value === $login ) {
            $log1 = TRUE;
        }
        if ($value === $senha ) {
            $log2 = TRUE;
        } 
    }
    if ($log1 and $log2) {
        break;
    }

}

if ($log1 and $log2) {
    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
    header("location: logado.php");
} else {
    echo '<h1>erro!</h1>';
}

?>
```